# Is there an opposite to Wake On LAN?

Tags: lan, remote, wake-on-lan

Would there be an easy way to remotely shut down a computer, like the opposite of Wake On LAN? I can easily use a program, such as an iOS App, where I just press a button and it starts up. Could I do the same in reverse? Such as press a button, and it shuts back down? What's the easiest way to do such a thing? Or is it not possible in the way that I described?

Comment: It will depend on the target OS.

Comment: My target machine is running Linux Mint (17.2)

Comment: I know that I can just ssh and run 'shutdown -h now' but I would like an easier solution for devices that dont have ssh but could just send the packet (or I guess aynthing else)

Comment: Truthfully, it'd be possible to write a simple daemon that listens for a specially crafted packet and triggers a shutdown, but I don't know of anything that actually does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of security and implementation. The quick answer is a **no**, there is not something such simple.

`Wakeup On LAN` (WOL [[1]](https://wiki.wireshark.org/WakeOnLAN)) is a protocol implemented at hardware level designed to minimize the effort needed to turn on a machine in an environment that requires high availability but not necessarily 24/7 operation (thus machines may be turned off). It is implemented at chipset level so that while the computer is plugged to power its Network Interface Card (NIC) will be listening for WoL packets. Once the packet arrives, it will trigger an ACPI power on signal that will start the boot process. Please understand that the computer is actually **turned on** even while off, but the power will be cut to most internal devices including fans and disks.

#### Security concern

Though WOL has (according to Wikipedia [[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN)) security implications *and* optional authentication mechanisms, they are generally less concerning than `Shutdown On LAN`. Let me better explain. If within a data center a malicious application starts sending plenties of random WOL packets to a number of server (consider cloud hosting environments where customers upload their applications), the worst damage they could do is an increase in power consumption at the facility. It can be later mitigated by the admins.

If such a Shutdown On LAN protocol did ever exist, one could bring down an entire datacenter possibly running an old-school DoS attack.

### Implementation considerations

This is relative. A Shutdown On LAN protocol might still be implementable. However please consider that power on event **can be handled** at hardware level (ACPI), while shutdown not. You can simply power a machine to bring it to life but you can't simply cut the power from an OLTP server without possibly losing data, so it's tightly dependant on the OS implementation to trigger a proper shutdown procedure. The opposite is OS independent.

However, a protocol **could** actually send an ACPI power event to the kernel which may choose how to handle it appropriately. Unfortunately (and we come again to security) ACPI has no authentication mechanism related to power events. In other words ACPI events reflect the press of a physical button, which is far from any computer security consideration. You can't let the hardware talk to the OS via ACPI **and** provide authentication.

### Conclusion

The simplemost way to implement Shutdown on LAN is by leveraging OS remote access capabilities. As already highlighted by @NoAngel, issuing an authenticated command via SSH or **Remote Powershell** [[3]](http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/). I am now trying this at home on Windows Server 2012 Datacenter

- Linux host: `ssh root@remotehost 'init 0'`
- Windows host: `Stop-Computer -ComputerName remotehost -Credential Administrator -Force`

Answer (score 0):

No such thing like the opposite of Wake On LAN. Just run poweroff remotely.

```
ssh root@host poweroff
```

Comment: :D yeah I guess that's really the only good way, this is just another one of my silly hypothetical ideas! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "Unified Remote" app has Wake, Sleep, Restart, and Shutdown.

You can even do it over WAN if you forward ports.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).